# вопрос по Си. как раздать карты?

Tags: c, разработка-игр

Карточная игра, в которой от 2 до 10 человек.
Для игры свыше 4 человек берется новая колода.

Подскажите, пожалуйста:

- как правильно раздать карты, чтобы у каждого игрока была хотя бы одна
  карта КАЖДОЙ масти?
- Как убрать те карты, которые уже были розданы?

Пытаюсь использовать struct Card, в котором хранится масть и значение карты. Мой метод пока только рандомно раздает масти (числа от 1 до 4) и сами карты (от 1 до 13). + метод который показывает эти карты.

```
void dealCards( Card playersCardsData[MAX_NUM_OF_PLAYERS][NUM_OF_CARDS], int numOfPlayers )
{
    for( int player = 0; player < numOfPlayers; player++ ) {
        for( int card = 0; card < NUM_OF_CARDS; card++ ) {
            playersCardsData[player][card].suit = rand() % 4 + 1; //generates  random numbers from 1 till 4 --> faces
            printf( "%2d | ", playersCardsData[player][card].suit );
            playersCardsData[player][card].value = rand() % 12 + 2; //generates random numbers from 2 till 14 
            //printf("%2d |", playersCardsData[player][card].value);
        } //inner for
        printf( "\n" );
    } //outer for
}

void diplayPlayersCards( Player players[MAX_NUM_OF_PLAYERS],
        Card playersCardsData[MAX_NUM_OF_PLAYERS][NUM_OF_CARDS], int numOfPlayers )
{
    printf( "PLAYERS DATA \n" );
    printf( "%3s %10s |", " ", " " );
    for( int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_CARDS; i++ ) {
        printf( "%2d   |", i + 1 );
    }
    printf(
            "\n----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n" );

    for( int playerIndex = 0; playerIndex < numOfPlayers; playerIndex++ ) {
        printf( "%3s %10s |", " ", players[playerIndex].name );

        for( int card = 0; card < NUM_OF_CARDS; card++ ) {
            switch( playersCardsData[playerIndex][card].suit ) {
                case 1:
                    printf( "%2c", 'H' );            //hearts

                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf( "%2c", 'D' );            //diamonds
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printf( "%2c", 'S' );            //spades
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printf( "%2c", 'C' );            //clubs
                    break;
            }
            if( 1 < playersCardsData[playerIndex][card].value
                    && playersCardsData[playerIndex][card].value < 11 ) {
                printf( "%2d |", playersCardsData[playerIndex][card].value );
            }
            else {
                switch( playersCardsData[playerIndex][card].value ) {
                    case 11:
                        printf( "%2c |", 'J' );            //jack
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        printf( "%2c |", 'Q' );            //queen
                        break;
                    case 13:
                        printf( "%2c |", 'K' );            //king
                        break;
                    case 14:
                        printf( "%2c |", 'A' );            //ace
                        break;
                }
            }
        }            // cards
        printf( "\n" );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

Comment: Я бы сначала разделил карты на масти и случайным образом выбрал для каждого игрока по одной карте каждой масти. Затем - остатки смешал бы и раздал оставшееся количество карт уже случайным образом из этого остатка.

Comment: "Как убрать те карты, которые уже были розданы?" - о чем речь? Убрать *откуда*?

Answer (score 2):

Я так понял вы просто берете, и случайно генерируете "карту" и даете ее игроку. Но при этом, так как это случайный процесс, карты повторяются - в чем нет ничего удивительного. Ваша ошибка в том, что этот процесс слишком случайный - у вас нет КОЛОДЫ! Вам нужно сначала создать колоду, вписать в нее значения, и из нее раздавать карты. При этом вам понадобится еще одна переменная - количество карт в колоде. Сейчас объясню алгоритм:

```
а = количество карт в колоде
b = rand () % a
раздаваемая карта = array [b]
array [b] = array [a-1]
a--
```

К этому алгоритму я пришел когда писал программу, создающую судоку. Таким образом карты у вас повторятся никогда не будут. Что касается раздачи каждой масти - это будет немного посложней. Я думаю для этого надо будет создать колоду не как одномерный массив, а с четырьмя строками, которые символизируют колоду. Тогда первые четыре карты вытаскиваешь по очереди из каждой строки, а следующие из псевдослучайной строки и псевдослучайного столбца. Чтобы полученные карты не резали глаза игроку - перетасоваваем их, и только тогда показываем игроку.

PS тот код со случайным вытаскиванием из колоды можно и не использовать (разве что только для выбора масти в случае четырехстрочного массива), а сначала перетасовывать ее и вытаскивать карты по-парядку.

Answer (score 1):

Вот может какие идеи пригодятся отсюда, будет работать и на C и на C++
ваша задача перерисовать на современный лад с применением ООП.

можно на массиве строк попробовать делать с применением методов их обработки, или списки использовать...
или вот так..

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int players_cards[5][14];  // [][]  матрица, карты на руках игроков
                           // [][0] выдано карт по мастям
                           // [0][0]количество полностью выданных мастей
                           // [0][] Зарезервировано
int players = 6;
int deals = 2;             // количество раздач после первой

void dispenser(int s, int p){                         // выдаём карту игроку
    int offset = rand() % (13 - players_cards[s][0]); // по случайному смещению
    int card = 1;

    while(players_cards[s][card] || offset){          // из списка имеющихся карт 
        if(!players_cards[s][card]) offset --;
        card++;
    }
    players_cards[s][card] = p;
    if (++players_cards[s][0] >= 13) 
          players_cards[0][0]++; // если не осталось карт этой масти, их выбор сокращается    
}

int main(void) {
    char cards[] = "2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  J  Q  K  A";
    char suits[] = " HDCS";

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0 ; i <= 4; i++)                            // обнуляем маccив выданных карт
        for(int j = 0 ; j <= 13; j++)   
            players_cards[i][j] = 0;

    for(int p = 1 ; p <=  players ; p++)                     // каждому игроку
        for(int suit = 1; suit <= 4; suit++)                 // каждой масти по 1   
            dispenser(suit, p);

    for(int k = 0; k < deals && players_cards[0][0] < 4; k++)   // и теперь то что осталось раздаём K раз
        for(int p = 1 ; p <= players && players_cards[0][0] < 4; p++){// каждому игроку
            int offset = rand() % (4 - players_cards[0][0]); // по случайному смещению
            int suit = 1;
                while(players_cards[suit][0] >= 13 || offset){ // из списка имеющихся мастей (выдано <13) 
                    if(players_cards[suit][0] < 13) offset--;
                    suit++;  
            }       
            dispenser(suit, p);
        }

printf(" | %s\n",cards);
printf("------------------------------------------\n"); 
for(int i = 1 ; i <= 4; i++){
    printf("%c|",suits[i]);
    for(int j = 1 ; j <= 13; j++)
        if (players_cards[i][j] > 0)
            printf("%2d ", players_cards[i][j]);
        else
            printf("   ");
    printf("| All cards: %d\n", players_cards[i][0]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Результат: (это матрица карт в которой проставлены номера игроков)

```
 | 2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  0  J  Q  K  A
------------------------------------------
H| 4  3     1  4  3  5  2  6  3        6 | All cards: 10
D| 4  1     3  6  2     1  5     5  6  5 | All cards: 10
C| 5  4  3  2     4           2     6  1 | All cards: 8
S| 1  5  2        4        1     6  3  2 | All cards: 8
```

Пример тут: [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/fYVw6R)

Comment: всем спасибо!!!